# 4 lines of Javascript is ruining my page

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

I have this piece of Javascript on my page. I include it from an external js-file.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $.noConflict();
    jQuery(".dato").fitText(1.2);
});
```

But it ruins some of the javascript in Twitter Bootstrap in TYPO3.

I can't see what is wrong.

If I comment it all out, there is no errors on the page.

Comment: WhaT is the console error?

Comment: Dont want to sound like a sadist but I like the question title :D

Comment: `$.noConflict` removes `$` from the `window`.

Comment: Can you pastr in the other code as well?

Comment: @V31 there is no need...

Comment: To debug, you should remove one line at a time.  Calculatus Eliminatus always helps an awful lot.

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing $ and jQuery selectors. Maybe this causes a conflict.

Try this:

```
$(".dato").fitText(1.2);
```

Check the HTML element which has the class "dato".